# Check if a property value was defined by developer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I am curious if there is any possibility to distinguish whether a property value was defined by a developer in C#/XAML or if it has default or computed value.

Something what Visual Studio provides in "Live Property Explorer".

I was looking at `Control.GetType().GetProperties()` but I did not find any specific property which could help me to identify if a property value was defined by developer or not.

For following `Grid` definition I would expect that `Background` property would be considered as locally defined value as you can see it in the screenshot from Visual Studio.

```
<Grid Background="Red"></Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: There is no way to determine this.

Comment: I believe the only way to do that is by looking at the code.

Comment: How do you define "computed value" ?

Comment: In the last essence *every* value is passed by the developer writing your program. Even if you knew a value came from a database who sais the DB wasn´t also created by that developer? If you want to ensure no-one manipulates your properties, just make their setter private or omit it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to achieve in general. In WPF however, for the concrete case to find out whether a dependency property has a local value or not, you may use `DependencyObject.ReadLocalValue`.

With

```
<Grid x:Name="grid"/>
```

the following expression would be true:

```
grid.ReadLocalValue(Panel.BackgroundProperty) == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
```

while for

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Red"/>
```

this would be true:

```
grid.ReadLocalValue(Panel.BackgroundProperty) == Brushes.Red
```

---

ReadLocalValue would also return a value other than `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` if the property was set to a resource, or a Binding, or any other [local value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).

Comment: This is very interesting. Do you happen to know if there is some similar approach for normal properties?

Comment: I can't imagine one. Standard .NET properties don't have a notion of different "value sources".

Comment: Thank you for the information. So I will accept your answer because it is very valuable for me.